# Visual Studio 2015 SSIS compatibility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis, visual-studio-2015

Does the 2012 SSIS install that was for VS2013 work in 2015 or does 2015 have the SSIS/BIDS and Reporting components built in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence (which is the edition you need for reporting) is only available for Visual Studio 2013.

The regular SSDT is available for Visual Studio 2015, but this is without the BI components!

Source: [Latest SSDT download page on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Comment: So do I install both 2013 and 2015?

Comment: @JohnSchultz - If you want SSDT reporting, that is indeed, what you need to do.  But as Jogai indicates you won't have access to the BI reports.

Comment: If you install SSDT-BI it will install the Visual Studio 2013 shell for you if you don't have it already. It wont affect your Visual Studio 2015 installation.

Comment: NP. Vote or mark as answer if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 2):

SSDT BI (with analysis services and reporting services) for Visual Studio 2015 is now available in the October Preview.  More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/10/27/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-october-2015.aspx